Aeron Archive replay last N messages
Suppose I have a live recording. When I start a service with business logic I want to read last N messages, if they are available. How to do it? I do the following:
long recordingPosition = archive.getRecordingPosition(recording.recordingId());
long startPosition = Math.max(recording.startPosition(), recordingPosition - N);

This code crashes with the following message:
ERROR - response for correlationId=63, error: 18480256 position not aligned to a data header, recordingId=122, sessionId=4304530350

I guess that my startPosition is not aligned to a message boundary. So the question is: how to determine a valid message boundary? I more or less don't care if it is expressed in bytes or messages. I just want to avoid replaying the whole recording on startup.

I think you treat Aeron Archive as Kafka or Rabbit, but it's not. Aeron is a low-level transport and Aeron Archive is just something that records the stream of data. You can think of it as a fancy way to write your data in a file.
So, with such a mindset, your question is more or less similar to "I'm writing my messages to a file and after a restart, I want to read the last N messages. How to do it?". And now it should be obvious that this code can't work because you subtract from "file position" the number of messages N.
long recordingPosition = archive.getRecordingPosition(recording.recordingId());
long startPosition = Math.max(recording.startPosition(), recordingPosition - N);

A dummy answer to how to find the correct position might be
long startPosition = Math.max(recording.startPosition(), recordingPosition - N * MESSAGE_SIZE);

but it will work only if all your messages are fixed size.
The more practical way could be to store the last read position somewhere and start from it. (I suppose you have any storage cos otherwise, why don't you want to read all the messages?)

Storing the last position is not what I need. When I restart a service with business logic I want to replay a short history. Is there way at least to start reading from the beginning of the last segment? Or last but one? I don't see any methods in AeronArchive which would give me the list of available segments.

Aeron Archive doesn't store the positions of the segments. As I said, it's more like a file where you have to do everything yourself =). So it's either start from the beginning or start from io.aeron.archive.client.AeronArchive#getRecordingPosition

Segments are fixed length and the start of a segment will be a message so can read forward from there. This goes further in that term boundaries are also message boundaries so you can further sub-divide segments.

To avoid having to replay all the history you could take snapshots of your service's state and with it store the position you currently are in.
The snapshot would be in a separated stream so that recording can always be replayed that from the last message... If your state won't fit in a single message you can fragment it into multiple messages and develop a protocol to signal the start of the snapshot and ofc the end.
